# e.target not always the trigger element

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Is there a way to use the trigger element (in that case the div with the "container" class) in the event callback function without another dom access? 
When clicking on the round dot `e.target = "round-btn"` so `e.target` isn't an option here.

```js
document.getElementsByClassName("container")[0].onclick = (e) => toggleSearchFilter(e);

function toggleSearchFilter(e) {
    e.target.classList.toggle("crossed-out");
}
```

```css
.container {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    user-select: none;
}

.round-btn {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-right: 5px;
    background-color: black;
}

.crossed-out{
    text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"><div class="round-btn"></div>Hello</div>
```

Comment: `e.target` is always the element which triggered the event. You need `e.currentTarget`, which is the element to which the event was attached to.

Comment: @Teemu alright thanks for the help, `e.currentTarget` worked fine but strange it didn't show when I logged `e`. If you post it as an answer I can close the question and you'll get rep. :)

Comment: Well, I suppose this has been already answered at SO, I just could'nt find a good post yet.